# Economic way to transfer money from China to U.S.?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer

I am a student in U.S.. My family in China would like to send me some money (about $30k)  to me by the end of this year, which can be done by single time or several times if necessary. Is there any way to do that with the minimum fee? Thanks!

I have following bank accounts with their debit cards:

- Fidelity individual investment accounts,
- Fidelity Individual Cash Management Account
- Capital One 360 checking account
- my previous university's credit union

I also have following credit cards:

- Citi Dividend World MasterCard;
- Amazon Chase Visa credit card
- American Express Blus Cash Everyday,
- Fidelity investment reward American Express

Comment: If it weren't as volatile as it is I would say Bitcoins.

Answer (score 3):

Regular wire transfer from bank to bank would be the easiest, safest, and likely the cheapest (next to carrying cash over the border) method.

Get the SWIFT info from the US bank you want the many land in (I believe all of the ones you mentioned support SWIFT wire transfers), and give it to your family in China. They'll have to find a local bank that supports SWIFT out-going transfers (might not be as easy as in the US) and send it out from there.

Other, more expensive, options would be Western Union/MoneyGram. Or carrying cash over the border, which in these amounts can trigger some questioning from the authorities.

Comment: Thanks! How about ACH transfer between banks in China and in U.S.? Is it more expensive than Wire tranfer between banks in the two countries?

Comment: @Tom there's no ACH between banks in China and in the US. ACH is a domestic system.